# Matching value of an array regardless of position in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I am trying to compare a string to an array using the following code:

```
var str = "ML00000";
var arr = ["MC", "CV", "ML", "LV"];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) 
{
   if (str.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) 
   {
    document.write("YES");
   }
   else
   {
   document.write("NO");
   }    
}
```

It is currently returning "NO NO YES NO" - I would like for the output to be either YES or NO when a match of the string has been found.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you - Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "LV00000";
var arr = ["MC", "CV", "ML", "LV"];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) 
{
   if (str.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) 
   {
    document.write("YES");
    break ;
   }
   if(i==len-1)  document.write("NO");
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, right way to say thanks is "Accept" answer and  up vote.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var exists = arr.some(function(item) {
    return str.indexOf(item) != -1;
});
```

This method returns true if at least one element returned true, then you can apply your logic:

```
if (exists) {
    document.write("YES");
}
else {
   document.write("NO");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: just change `str.indexOf(item) != -1;`

Comment: ES6: `arr.some(x => str.includes(x))`